# tikz automata start arrow customization

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

I have one automata FSA as below.

I wish to customize the start arrow with a big dot, and keep the arrow 2pt to the target.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows,automata}
\def\dx{1cm} \def\dy{1.5cm}
\tikzstyle{state}=[draw,ellipse]
\newcommand{\newState}[4]{\node[state,#3](#1)[#4]{#2};}
\newcommand{\newTransition}[4]{\path[->] (#1) edge [#4] node {#3} (#2);} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=\dy and \dx,
  >=latex,shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt,auto,
  semithick  %semithick, thick, thin semithick
  ]
  \newState{S}{$SS$}{initial below,initial text={}}{}
  \newState{q1}{$QQ1$}{right=of S}{}
  \newState{q2}{$QQ2$}{below=of q1}{}
  \newState{q3}{$QQ3$}{right=of q1}{accepting} 

  \newTransition{S}{q1}{aa}{}
  \newTransition{q1}{q2}{bb}{bend left}
  \newTransition{q2}{q1}{cc}{bend left}
  \newTransition{q1}{q3}{dd}{}
  \draw[<-] (S) -- node[midway,sloped,below,rotate=180] {start} ++(0,-\dy) [fill] circle (4pt);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My question is:

1. The start arrow didn't keep the 2pt distance from the target.
2. Is this right way to draw such a big dot?
3. The start text direction need to be rotate 180,is it right way to do it?

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of manually drawing the initial arrow, I'd suggest you to use the `initial distance` key and the `every initial by arrow` style to customize the appearance. For example, you could use

```
initial distance=1cm,
every initial by arrow/.style={*->}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows,automata}

\def\dx{1cm} 
\def\dy{1.5cm}

\tikzset{
  state/.style={draw,ellipse}
}

\newcommand{\newState}[4]{\node[state,#3](#1)[#4]{#2};}
\newcommand{\newTransition}[4]{\path[->] (#1) edge [#4] node {#3} (#2);} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=\dy and \dx,
  >=latex,shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt,auto,
  semithick,  %semithick, thick, thin semithick
  initial distance=1cm,
  every initial by arrow/.style={*->}
  ]
  \newState{S}{$SS$}{initial below}{}
  \newState{q1}{$QQ1$}{right=of S}{}
  \newState{q2}{$QQ2$}{below=of q1}{}
  \newState{q3}{$QQ3$}{right=of q1}{accepting} 

  \newTransition{S}{q1}{aa}{}
  \newTransition{q1}{q2}{bb}{bend left}
  \newTransition{q2}{q1}{cc}{bend left}
  \newTransition{q1}{q3}{dd}{}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Great idea, but how can we draw the init text "start" sloped on the arrow, just as style in my original diagram?

Comment: @Beatlej I think that it's better not to rotate the "start" text, but if you want to do it, you'll need to set `initial text={}` in the `tikzpicture` and then place the text manually with something like   `\node[rotate=90,anchor=north east] at (S.south) {start};`